Accessing the list of offered Completions for filtering purposes within Extension
I am looking into developing simple Extension for VS-Code/IntelliJ, while on IntelliJ side I know everything need to achieve my goal, I was unable to find much relevant stuff when it comes to VS-Code.
I need to get the list of all provided autocompletions - ideally before they are rendered, and then remove some completions as needed.
So far I know about CompletionItemProvider and how to use it to add new completions, but I was unable to find anything relevant to manipulating other completions
Is there anything that can be done here?

There's no way to do that. All extensions which provide code completion implement that completion provider and VS Code uses them internally. You have no access to them in your extension.

You can get the list of completions at a position with vscode.executeCompletionItemProvider but I doubt you can manipulate the list of completions another extension provides.  You might see what happens if you re-issue the edited list of completionItems in your CompletionProvider to see if your items get priority  - which could be helpful.
